# MDX query adding SUM column

Tags: sql, mdx, olap-cube, ssas-2008

I have written the following MDX

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[SumReturns] AS
  ([Dimension1].[GCode].defaultmember,[Measures].[GScore Sum])  

SELECT
   non empty  
   (  

      {[Dimension1].[Description].children},  
      {[Dimension1].[GCode].children},  
      {
         [Measures].[GScore Sum],  
         [Measures].[SumReturns]  
      }

   )  
   on columns,  
   non empty
   (
      [Dimension2].[DCode].[DCode] *  
      [Dimension2].[DName].[DName] *   
      [Dimension2.[Barcode].[Barcode] *  
      [Dimension2].[LN].[LName] *  
      [Dimension2].[FN].[FName]   

   )
   on rows
FROM [MCube]
WHERE 
(
   {[Dimension2].[HARC].[DCode].&[0000]}
)
```

The query is giving me the results below:

[image: Actual Results]

But what I expected instead was these results:

[image: Expected Results]

Any suggestions on how to get the desired results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here  is the query that worked to get the required results. No need of calculated measure

```
 select  
    non empty  
    (      
    [Dimension1].[Description].children,  
    [Dimension1].[GCode].members,  
    [Measures].[GScore Sum]   
    )  
    on columns,  
    non empty
    (
    [Dimension2].[DCode].[DCode] *  
    [Dimension2].[DName].[DName] *   
    [Dimension2.[Barcode].[Barcode] *  
    [Dimension2].[LN].[LName] *  
    [Dimension2].[FN].[FName]   

    )
    on rows
    from 
    [MCube]
    where 
    (

    {[Dimension2].[HARC].[DCode].&[0000]}

    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not summing up SubCat1 and SubCat2? why do you select the default member? is it all?

to sum them up this is the code you will need:

```
with member [Dimension1].[GCode].[SumReturns] as
SUM([Dimension1].[Description].children , [Measures].[GScore Sum])

select  
non empty  
(  

[Dimension1].[Description].children * 
[Dimension1].[GCode].children

)  
on columns,  
non empty
(
[Dimension2].[DCode].[DCode] *  
[Dimension2].[DName].[DName] *   
[Dimension2.[Barcode].[Barcode] *  
[Dimension2].[LN].[LName] *  
[Dimension2].[FN].[FName]   

)
on rows
from 
[MCube]

where 
(



{[Dimension2].[HARC].[DCode].&[0000]}

)
```

Comment: @OrenHeig:    
SUbcat1 and SUbcat2 is just an example , I have unlimited categories and multiple subcategories in each category.